# Data is not being saved in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm making an app and I'm trying to store data in Firebase Authentication and Realtime Database with Android Studio. However, the data I'm saving to Realtime database doesn't get saved.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
reference = db.getReference("Users");

button_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        email = binding.email.getText().toString();
        password = binding.password.getText().toString();
        firstName = binding.firstName.getText().toString();
        lastName = binding.lastName.getText().toString();
        userName = binding.username.getText().toString();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        // Create a new user with email and password using Firebase Authentication
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(Register.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // User registration successful
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            Log.d("class", "class");
                            // Save the user's additional information to Firebase Realtime Database
                            Users userData = new Users(email, password, firstName, lastName, birthday, userName);
                            reference.child(userName).setValue(userData);

                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // Clear input fields
                            binding.firstName.setText("");
                            binding.lastName.setText("");
                            binding.username.setText("");
                            binding.email.setText("");
                            binding.password.setText("");

                            // Redirect to the main activity or any other desired activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // If sign-up fails, display an error message
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registration failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
});
```

The realtime database data doesn't get stored only the Firebase authentication. There's no explicit error from Logcat.

Comment: I recommend debugging the code you shared locally and telling us the results of that. So: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `setValue()` operation, to see if something went wrong? Please respond using @AlexMamo